# A quick example to train a model batch by batch in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I have searched a lot on Google, I couldn't find an example of training a model batch by batch. The mnist built in Tensorflow dataset has `mnist.train.next_batch(BATCH_SIZE)` function, I need a function like this to separate my dataset into batches and loads the next batch for every iteration.

Comment: The source code for next_batch is freely available.  You could certainly reuse that code for your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your train data as follows:

```
#Generate a random batch of 200 samples
rand_index = np.random.choice(len(x_data), size=200)
rand_x = x_data[rand_index]
rand_y = y_data[rand_index]
```

And then at each iteration, you train batch by batch.

```
for i in range(1000):
   for u in range(number_of_batches):
      sess.run(train, feed_dict={x: rand_x.....})
```

Something like that would work.

Comment: currently I'm training the same way, but for each model,I need to calculate number_of_batches and the no. of batches per iteration manually and it mad for complex models,