# ArrayMemoryError with .concatenate() in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, neural-network, concatenation

I am learning how to create neural networks, and I have made a neural network for training that distinguishes cats from dogs. The neural network had low accuracy (0.50) when I trained it on 100 photos of cats and dogs. Now I have downloaded a Google dataset for 10,000 photos of cats, and the same number of dogs. I normalized the files, converted them to .npy and started training the neural network. As a result, these warnings appeared in the first 20 seconds of operation:

```
2024-01-07 15:09:51.166129: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\artyo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py:2976: The name tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy instead.
```

But it seems to me that this is not particularly important, these warnings have been before, they do not affect the work. But after about 15-20 minutes of work (nothing happens all this time, only the Python process takes about 13 gigs of RAM), the neural network outputs the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Unity\!!neuro\projects\catsAndDogs100\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    train_data = np.concatenate((cats_train_data, dogs_train_data), axis=0)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 10.1 GiB for an array with shape (9000, 224, 224, 3) and data type float64
```

As I understand it, this is something related to a lack of some kind of memory, and this error occurs even before training, at the moment of combining arrays with cats and dogs. At the time of launching the program, 200 gigabytes are available on the disk on which the neural network files are located, 150 gigabytes on the system disk, and about 14 gigs of RAM are free at the time of launch. I have already tried to reduce the number of images in the dataset from 12,500 to 9900, as a result, only the number of "inaccessible" gigabytes in the error text decreased.
Code with concatenation:

```
# Загрузка данных кошек для обучения
cats_train_data = [np.load("E:\\Unity\\!!neuro\\datasets\\catsAndDogs100\\finishedCats1\\" + filename) for filename in os.listdir("E:\\Unity\\!!neuro\\datasets\\catsAndDogs100\\finishedCats1\\")]
cats_train_labels = np.zeros(len(cats_train_data))  # Метки для кошек

# Загрузка данных собак для обучения
dogs_train_data = [np.load("E:\\Unity\\!!neuro\\datasets\\catsAndDogs100\\finishedDogs1\\" + filename) for filename in os.listdir("E:\\Unity\\!!neuro\\datasets\\catsAndDogs100\\finishedDogs1\\")]
dogs_train_labels = np.ones(len(dogs_train_data))   # Метки для собак

# Объединение данных и меток для обучения
train_data = np.concatenate((cats_train_data, dogs_train_data), axis=0)
train_labels = np.concatenate((cats_train_labels, dogs_train_labels), axis=0)
```

I tried to reduce the amount of data in the dataset, and I also tried to give the process python.exe high priority and ask this question on the Russian version of Stackoverflow, but no one there has answered me.

Comment: This sounds like a problem caused by a dataset being too big. It's a little weird that it won't allocate 10GB if 14 GB is left, but even if you got that to work, it would leave only 4GB for training the neural network. I think you should try reducing the size of the dataset.

Comment: @NickODell can the program request video memory instead of RAM? How much should I reduce the number of images to if the program requires 10 gigabytes for 10,000 images?

Comment: It seems your issue is with the amount of data you are loading at a time. In order to train on this set you will need to load it in batches.
There are some recommendations on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60143153/is-there-a-way-in-tensorflow-to-load-batches-of-data-each-time and this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389858/a-quick-example-to-train-a-model-batch-by-batch-in-tensorflow
If you post some example code that replicates the issue we can take a look.

Comment: @BitsAreNumbersToo I added the code. I don't understand how to implement concatenation by batches.

Comment: @Yazik72 No, `np.concatenate()` will always allocate memory from RAM, not video memory. I suppose you could [memmap](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) a file, and use `np.concatenate(..., out=array)`, where `array` is the memory mapped file, but at that point it's basically just loading the data in batches, but more complex.

Comment: As a temporary solution, I lowered the number of images from 10,000 to 3,000 and the training went fine. Later I will try to connect different batches.

Answer (score 0):

I have put together a small code example that shows how you can train on partial sets so that they don't all need to be loaded into memory at once.

1. Choose a batch size that meets your system limitations
2. Identify the data and collect it all with labels and shuffle it up
3. Determine how many batches to use based on total size and batch size
4. Iterate epochs time (to maintain multi-epoch training that normally keras offers out of the box)
5. Iterate through each batch, loading the images as necessary, and fitting the model to it

I copied the basic setup for a neural network classifier from tensorflow's website. In your case, you will not use `N` and you will list the training data using the code in the comment, which is based on your example above. I just downloaded a random cat and dog image to verify that the code worked. You may also need to edit the line in the loop that loads the data to work with your files.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
import random

N = 90
batch_size = 10
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
epochs = 5

cat_file_set = [(0, 'cat.jpg')] * N  # (0, x) for x in list(os.listdir("E:\\ ... Cats1\\"))
dog_file_set = [(1, 'dog.jpg')] * N  # (1, x) for x in list(os.listdir(E:\\ ... Dogs1\\"))
file_set = cat_file_set + dog_file_set
random.shuffle(file_set)
total_batches = int(np.ceil(len(file_set) / batch_size))

# https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss_fn, metrics=['accuracy'])

for epochnum in range(epochs):
    for batchnum in range(total_batches):
        bslice = file_set[batchnum * batch_size: (batchnum + 1) * batch_size]
        train_data = np.array([np.array(Image.open(x[1])) for x in bslice])
        train_labels = np.array([x[0] for x in bslice])
        model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=1)
# model.evaluate(train_data, train_labels, verbose=2)
```

Let me know if you have any questions.