Is there a way to train a KNN model partially on multiple datasets?
I am working with a very large datasets consisting of the data of 50 (total of 150 GB) participants. The concatenated/merged data file is so large that my computer keeps running into memory errors. Because of this, I am looking into methods to partially train my KNN model on each dataset, so I can wipe the datasets it already trained on from RAM. My pc has 32 GB of RAM.
This might be very simple, but I have been cracking my head over it. Is there any way to do this?
Rough example of what I imagine it to look like:
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=6)

for participant in participant_list: 

    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_of_this_participant) 

    X_train = df.drop(Column_name) 
    y_train = df[Column_name]

    knn.partial_fit(X_train, y_train, classes=np.unique(y_train)) 
    #something like the line above to partially train it

    del df 


#And then another for loop would follow to test it.

I have tried Feature Selection and Principal Component Analysis to make the merged dataset more memory efficient, but the KNN still ran into memory errors.
I have tried working with a loop that goes over chunks of the data and trains and tests the KNN model in that loop, but that still eventually ran into memory issues. Even if it had worked, I would have just had a bunch of results for a knn model trained on only partial data and I would have to average that for my final result, so that doesn't seem optimal.

Is it for a company or a university? Run it on cloud? What's very large datasets?

I have an answer on another post with the same issue, does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77774314

maybe you could ask on similar portal DataScience or CrossValidated

@BitsAreNumbersToo I will try that and update the post afterward.

@Emily Here is sklearn's guide to working with large data which may be worth a read also, I noticed that some sklearn models override previous training when you re-call fit which is what's in my linked post, so that may not be a solution to your problem.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/computing/scaling_strategies.html

During inference, i.e., prediction time, a KNN models needs access to the training data to find the nearest training instance. If your dataset has a size of 150 GB, a KNN model probably is not the best choice.
In my point of view, you have at least three alternatives:
1.) If your dataset contains a lot of redundant data points, you could just downsample the data.
2.) Partition your data such that individual models are trained on each partition.
3.) Use an algorithm and implementation that is able to deal with large training datasets. You might start with XGBoost: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/external_memory.html
